# Firefox Bookmarks between computers?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to sync firefox add-ons and bookmarks between machines](https://superuser.com/questions/2528/best-way-to-sync-firefox-add-ons-and-bookmarks-between-machines)

I was wondering if there was a way to use the same bookmarks between computers? I know you can export your bookmarks from one computer and put them on another but then eventually i've saved a bunch of things as bookmarks between the computers and it's a hassle reorganizing. And having to import/export each time.

It'd be nice if there was a way i could stash the bookmark backup file on a server or something and have it reload into firefox when i start it up.

Is this possible? I've never done anything with a browser before so i wouldn't know how to design it or whether the design of firefox would even allow me to do it.

So i guess i'm asking whether it's possible, and what i'd have to learn to make it happen? Or if something like that already exists.

Answer (score 9):

[xmarks.com](http://www.xmarks.com/)  arguably the best bookmark syncing plugin for firefox.

This also should probably be on superuser.

Comment: +1 for Xmarks. It even supports multiple "profiles" so you can use the same Xmarks account for separate purposes (home, work, wife, etc.).

Comment: Like Firefox Sync, Xmarks also allows you to store the backup on your own site if you prefer that.

Answer (score 3):

[Firefox Sync](http://mozillalabs.com/sync/) (previously Weave) from [Mozilla Labs](http://mozillalabs.com/) is the complete syncing tool for Firefox. It enables you to sync bookmarks, history, settings, passwords and even open tabs between Windows, Linux, Mac and mobile versions of Firefox (Fennec). You can select which of the properties are used, so you can use Sync to synchronize only bookmarks, if you so desire.

Firefox sync uses either Mozilla's servers as their data storage, or you may [set up your own Sync server](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/Sync/1.0/Setup). Anyhow, the data are completely encrypted, so there shouldn't be any [privacy concerns](https://services.mozilla.com/privacy-policy/).

Comment: FireFox has been pushing this plugin a **lot** lately

Answer (score 0):

GMarks is good if you use Google bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com) is what I use. I have it for Firefox, IE, and Chrome, to keep my bookmarks available for all the browsers I use.

According to their site it is also available for Safari, but I can not attest to its viability there, as I do not use Safari.

Also, you can access your bookmarks directly from the Xmarks site, should you be somewhere without access to your own browser, or where you can not run your portable version, such as a public site that will not allow USB access, or blocking the installation of extensions to their default browsers.

I personally use one profile for work, and another for my personal use.